# Not able to connect to Azure server using "NET USE <drive>..." command

Tags: azure, remote-access, remote-server, azure-virtual-machine

I have subscription to Azure server running Windows 2008 Server r2 Datacentre, 64-Bit.  I have shared a folder in the root of its C drive with full permission to 'Everyone' (along with default users/groups).  Both Azure Windows firewall and my local system Firewall are OFF.  No other changes have been made in Azure from the default settings.  In Azure control panel, Site URL of Cloud service and DNS of Virtual Machine are showing same and the Public IP of both Cloud service and Virtual machine are same.

Now, when I am trying to map this shared folder remotely using the below command,

```
NET USE Z: \\<IPaddress>\<sharedfoldername> /USER:<username> <password> /PERSISTENT:NO
```

I am getting,
"System error 53 has occured.
The network path was not found"

But, I am able to connect to the machine through RDP with the same user!
So, what I am missing?  Is there any other settings required in Azure to allow this?

Thanks in advance,
Rajesh Karunakaran

### EDIT ON 08-Feb-2017 (Just to explain a bit more deeper)

In our Azure subscription, we have Storage account, Virtual Machine, Virtual Network & Cloud service.  After setting up a Folder Share in Storage Account, I am able to map that folder within the Azure VM using

```
NET USE Z: \\<IPaddress>\<sharedfoldername> /USER:<username> <password> /PERSISTENT:NO
```

But, what I want to achieve is to be able to access the Share Folder in Azure from my local system (I am not in US) through mapping a drive the same way.  But from my local system, when I issue the same command it says
"system error 5... Access Denied"

I have opened Port 445 (File sharing....) in Azure server by logging in through RDP.  (Anyway, the Firewall is OFF and I assume then port opening is insignificant)

Interestingly, when we'd taken Azure trial account (for 30 days), I was able to connect to a normal windows Shared Folder through 'NET USE' command from my local system.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What ISP you use? ISP could block port 445, then you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mount file between client and server. The port 445 could be communication.

According to your description, please check as the following steps:

1.Open port 445 on Azure NSG(Inbound rules)

2.Click [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32346.azure-summary-of-isps-that-allow-disallow-access-from-port-445.aspx) to see the summary of ISPs that allow or disallow access from port 445.

You could use [Portquery](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17148) to check whether port 445 is open.

```
PortQry.exe -n [storage account name].file.core.windows.net -p TCP -e 445
```

More information about how to troubleshoot this issue please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-troubleshoot-file-connection-problems#error-53-or-error-67-when-you-try-to-mount-or-unmount-an-azure-file-share).

Comment: Dear Walter,

Thank you for your reply.

The Firewall is off on my system and Azure.  So, this port opening has anything to do with the connection issue.  Btw, how do I open the port in Azure NSG?

Thanks

Comment: Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-nsg-arm-portal#manage-associations) You need open 445 on Inbound rules.

Comment: Yes, please.  I am editing the question as 'comment' doesn't allow content length beyond a limit.

Comment: @RajeshKarunakaran On Azure network, Azure does not block port 445. But your ISP maybe block port 445.

Comment: @RajeshKarunakaran Now, you could mount your `C` to other Azure VM but could not mount on your local PC?

Comment: Thank you for your time.
"NET USE" works when I try to map the Share Folder of Azure Storage in Azure Server itself.  This I did by accessing the Azure server through RDP.  However, I am not able to map a drive in my local system (outside of Azure network/location/premises whatever!) to the azure Storage Shared folder using the same command.  Thats the issue!

Comment: @RajeshKarunakaran That is not Azure's issue. You could try to contact you ISP and ensure whether block port 445. Many ISPs could block the port. Also you could use `PortQry` to check.

Comment: @RajeshKarunakaran You could check this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c233a589-853c-447a-aad4-34130473574a/azure-storage-accounts-file-service-on-premise-mapping-fail?forum=windowsazuredata)

Comment: the link you gave is indeed in details it seems.  will follow your advice and contact you again if in need.  thank you.

Comment: @RajeshKarunakaran Mount Azure file share need samba 3.0. Mount your file does not need this requirement.

Comment: As i have seen version of Windows mentioned in the link, I just tried to map it from my client's Windows 10 system and it worked just fine.
So, now I have make sure if its my Windows (its 7 prof.) or ISP causing the problem in my system.  Thank you very much.